# Calling res.sendStatus() after sending an email with nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

So I have my implementation of a POST request handler in `express.js`:

```
.post(function(req, res) {

    ((data selection and processing from mongo...))

    var bcast = mailer.prepareBcast(data[0]);

    mailer.send(bcast).then(
        function(success) {
            console.log(success);
            res.sendstatus(200);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.sendStatus(555);
        }
    );

    ((...))
});
```

Email is sent by the `mailer.send()` method, the `success-callback` gets executed and outputs the `success` variable contents which is the return value from nodemailer(used with gmail transporter). The thing is that `res.sendStatus(200)` is not executed and my frontend waits for a confirmation that sending an email was successful (or not). What am I doing wrong here? Perhaps I can't send anything back after the email was sent? I'm still fairly new to node so sorry if this is some obvious question...

Comment: `sendstatus !== sendStatus`

Comment: Omg, I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake. Thank you @robertklep.